# How to detect if a check box is selected using MVC3 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, checklistbox

As I am new to MVC framework, I have been spending a couple of hours to generate a check box list in a View file. Finally, I could figure it out well. Here is my code:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.GetRoleNames)
        {
            @Html.CheckBox("chk_" + item.Value, new { value = item.Value })@item.Text<br />
        }
```

But, I need to detect which of them is selected and if all the ckeckboxes are left unchecked, then preventing some operations.

**Question:** How can I get the checked items when I am within a controller action?

Comment: Is the check box backed by a `bool` type property or field?

Comment: First, Thanks you for edition. Actually, 'GetRoleNames' is property within the related ViewModel which returns 'SelectList'.

Comment: You are going to want to use a bool for the actual checkbox. There should be plenty of info if you search around on binding a list of bools or other custom objects back to the controller. A SelectList is not a checkbox or list of them.

Comment: @merekel: Appreciate it

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181948/how-to-use-auto-postback-with-checkboxes-and-dropdowns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others said, you should use a Boolean value as the second parameter to CheckBox to indicate the checked status. A bit of string manipulation should help you get the ids of the **selected** check boxes..

First lets change the way the checkbox helper is used

```
<div id='myCheckboxDiv'>
 @foreach (var item in Model.GetRoleNames)
 {
   @Html.CheckBox("chk_" + item.Value, false)@item.Text<br />
 }
</div>
```

As you can see, I have set the second parameter to false and wrapped the mix in a div

And, when you want to get the ‘values’ associated with the selected checkboxes

```
var values = $(‘# myCheckboxDiv’).find('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {

  // get the name ..
  var nameOfSelectedItem = this.attr('name');

  // skip the ‘chk_’ part and give me the rest
  return nameOfSelectedItem.substr(4);

}).get();
```

I am assuming ***item.Value*** to be a number. If its is not, please remove the white spaces using C#